Quotients of modules over DVRs
I'm trying to prove the following: Let $A$ be a DVR with uniformizer $\pi\in A$ and finite residue field $A/(\pi)$, and let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$.
Consider $A$-modules $M_0 \subseteq M_1 \subseteq M_2 \subseteq K^2$ which are generated by two $K$-linear independent basis elements each.
Suppose that $M_2/M_1 \cong A/(\pi)$, and write $M_1/M_0 \cong A/(\pi^a) \oplus A/(\pi^b)$ according to the structure theorem.
Claim: We have one of
$$
M_2/M_0 \cong
\begin{cases}
A/(\pi^a) \oplus A/(\pi^{b+1}),\\
A/(\pi^{a+1}) \oplus A/(\pi^b).
\end{cases}
$$

I think this proof is faulty: Write $M_2/M_0 \cong A/(\pi^{a'}) \oplus A/(\pi^{b'})$.
Then $M_1/M_0$ is a submodule of $M_2/M_0$, so we have $a\le a'$ and $b\le b'$.
If $\lvert A/(\pi)\rvert =: q$, then by Lagrange,
$$
q = |M_2/M_1| = \frac{|M_2/M_0|}{|M_1/M_0|} = \frac{q^{a'+b'}}{q^{a+b}}.
$$
Hence $(a',b')$ is either $(a+1,b)$ or $(a,b+1)$. $\square$
I think the bold part is very wrong since modules are weird.
If we assume that $a\le b$, what is definitely true is that $\pi^b M_1/M_0 = 0$ and $\pi M_2/M_1 = 0$, so $\pi^b M_1 \subseteq M_0$ and $\pi M_2 \subseteq M_1$.
Hence $\pi^{b+1} M_2 \subseteq M_0$, so $a', b' \le b+1$.
But what about the cases where $(a',b')$ is $(a+2,b-1)$ or similar?

The claim is true and there is the following elementary proof. However, it requires some knowledge on $A$-lattices.
By the structure theorem, we may write $M_2/M_0 \cong A/(\pi^\alpha) \oplus A/(\pi^\beta)$ with $\alpha \le \beta$. Moreover, we may assume that $a \le b$. We proceed in three steps.

Show that $\beta \le b+1$. Note that $\pi^b$ annihilates $M_1/M_0$, and so $\pi^b M_1 \subseteq M_0$. By a similar argument, $\pi M_2 \subseteq M_1$, whence $\pi^{b+1} M_2 \subseteq M_0$. Since $M_2/M_0$ is annihilated by $\pi^\beta$, we must have $\beta \le b+1$.

Show that $\alpha \le a+1$. Note that $M_0,M_1,M_2$ are $2$-dimensional $A$-lattices. Since $M_2 \cong A^2$, w.l.o.g. assume that $M_2 = A^2$. Then we can write $M_1 = X A^2$ for some $X \in \mathrm{Mat}_2(A) \cap \mathrm{GL}_2(K)$ (take the basis of $M_1$ w.r.t. $A^2$ for $X$). By the elementary divisor theorem, we can decompose $X$ into $X = L\operatorname{diag}(1,\pi)R$ where $L,R \in \mathrm{GL}_2(A)$. Since $A^2$ is $\mathrm{GL}_2(A)$-stable, we may assume w.l.o.g. that $M_2 = A^2$ and $M_1 = \operatorname{diag}(1, \pi) A^2$ (multiply from the left by $L^{-1}$).
Similary, by considering $M_0 \subseteq M_1$, we can write $M_0 = \operatorname{diag}(1,\pi) Y A^2$ with $Y \in \mathrm{Mat}_2(A) \cap \mathrm{GL}_2(K)$. Again by a decomposition $Y = L\operatorname{diag}(\pi^a,\pi^b)R$ with $L,R \in \mathrm{GL}_2(A)$, we have $M_0 = \operatorname{diag}(1,\pi) L \operatorname{diag}(\pi^a, \pi^b) A^2$.
Again similarly, by considering $M_0 \subseteq M_2$, we have $M_0 = L' \operatorname{diag}(\pi^\alpha,\pi^\beta) A^2$ for some $L' \in \mathrm{GL}_2(A)$. Since the stabiliser of $A^2$ in the $\mathrm{GL}_2(K)$ action from the left is $\mathrm{GL}_2(A)$, we must have $$\operatorname{diag}(1,\pi)L\operatorname{diag}(\pi^a,\pi^b) = L'\operatorname{diag}(\pi^\alpha,\pi^\beta)R \qquad (*)$$ for some $R \in \mathrm{GL}_2(A)$.
Let $\gcd \in A$ denote the greatest common divisor of the four matrix entries of either product in $(*)$, and let $v$ be the discrete valuation on $A$. On the right-hand side, we have $\alpha \le v(\gcd)$. On the left-hand side, we have $v(\gcd) \le a+1$, for otherwise, $\pi^{a+2} \mid v(\gcd)$. Write $L = \begin{pmatrix}w & x \\ y & z\end{pmatrix}$. Then the left column of the left-hand side is $(\pi^a w, \pi^{a+1} y)^\top$, and the left column is divisible by $\pi^{a+2}$. We conclude that $\pi \mid w,y$, and so $\pi \mid wz - xy = \det L$, i.e. $\det L \notin A^\times$, and hence the contradiction $L \notin \mathrm{GL}_2(A)$. Alltogether, $\alpha \le a+1$.

Show that $\alpha+\beta=a+b+1$. This follows readily by considering the valuation of the determinant of $(*)$.


These three steps show that $(\alpha,\beta) \in \{(a+1,b), (a,b+1)\}$. $\square$
Edit: The hypothesis that $A/(\pi)$ shall be finite is unnecessary, it seems.
